# Video does not resize and remains on top: VLC and Skype and other programs

Tags: video, skype, vlc, resize

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10 on an Asus UX305. When I open a video I can't resize it, and it flickers blue when I resize it.

I show the problem here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBL2BAU8Vyk

I have this issue with VLC but also with Skype. For VLC there is a workaround (which I show in the video) but not for Skype. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

As i've already [said](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBL2BAU8Vyk) , the solution is [here](https://github.com/linuxenko/ubuntu-skylake-i915-video-fix) . I'm trying to maintain it, there is alot of different things related to skylake video drivers.

Comment: Awesome! This solved my problem very easily.

Comment: I had same problem as the OP, running Ubuntu 16.04 on a NUC6i5.  This solution worked like a charm!

Answer (score 4):

I just had a very similar problem as in the video, but I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and only use Intel Graphics.
The problem started after I installed `vdpauinfo` and `libvdpau-va-gl1`, because VLC was complaining about their absence.

Removing them fixed the problem virtually instantaneously:

```
sudo apt-get remove vdpauinfo libvdpau-va-gl1
```

Comment: Worked for me too.